# Posting Github CodeReview Comments to Private Slack Messages

Tags: github, slack-api, slack, github-codereviews

I want to connect **GitHub** and **Slack** in a very specific way.
When a comment to a Github CodeReview is written, the user who has committed the code should get the comment as private message.

Now I can do is to integrade slack and github with normal slack channel integrations or IFTT or Zapier.

But in this case all messages (also pull and commit messages) are fetched and i can only post them to a generic channel, not private message.

I also tried ot use the @username: syntax, but the text is always wrapped in a text block it is not evaluated.

The only thing  I can think of is currently to write it on my own by using the github and slack api. But I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Any hints if there is something I'm not seeing?

Comment: I am not aware of any github app for Slack that does that so you would proberbly need to write this integration yourself. The main challenge will be to match github users to slack users, but I guess that could by achieved by matching the email address.

Comment: On your second point about the @username syntax: I recently wrote a bot that solves this. You can see more in the readme: https://github.com/petrgazarov/engineer-notifier

Comment: @ErikKalkoken in my case i can map them manually so this is not a problem.
PetrGazarov thx i'll have a look at this